# Using Visual Basic to open and log into another program

Tags: vb.net, focus, textfield

I am trying to create a visual basic application that will open VPN and log in.  The problems I am having is setting the focus on a specific field before it performs an action.

The other problem is that this isn't an event driven login process either, I am masking assumptions that the cursor will always be in the right position when this script runs.  So if I can guarantee the position of the cursor when the script starts that will help.  If it can be handled more as an event then that will be better.

I can do the research if I am given the right topic to research.

Here is an example of the code.

```
Dim a As New Process

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    a.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe"
    a.Start()
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.SendWait("vpn.business.com")
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("username")
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}")
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("password")
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't keep the mouse on one position all the time but if you want to change the position you can use this:

```
 Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)
```

So you are using AnyConnect. The problem is that a unknown process can not completely track if another application have focus, if another button got pressed and so on. I would not just hope for it that the user do nothing before the login is done.

The best way (because you are using AnyConnect) is to avoid the GUI completely. You can use the `vpncli.exe` that's included in the AnyConnect Installer. This will make things a lot easier, because you are now working with command shell. According to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/644441), it should be enough to have a text file containing the login data and launch this with the command line. Lets start with the code!

Maybe you need to import following first:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
```

So first of all we need to create a txt file with the login info and then start the program with it

```
'dim the cisco path, change it if its not there
Dim CiscoPath As String = Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86 & "\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\" 
Private Sub VPNfilecheck()
'check if vpncli.exe exists
    If File.Exists(CiscoPath & "vpncli.exe") Then
    'check if login file already exists and delete it.
        If File.Exists(CiscoPath & "awesomelogin.dat") Then  
            File.Delete(CiscoPath & "awesomelogin.dat")
        Else
    Else
        MsgBox("AnyConnect not found")
        Return
    End If
    'lets create the file
    Try
       Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(CiscoPath & "awesomelogin.dat")
       fs.Close()
       Using addInfo = File.CreateText(CiscoPath & "awesomelogin.dat")
             addInfo.WriteLine("connect myvpnhost")
             addInfo.WriteLine("myloginname")
             addInfo.WriteLine("mypasswordname")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't write login file. Please try it again as an admin. That should work.")
        Return
    End Try
    Try 
    'time for cisco
        Process.Start(CiscoPath & "vpncli.exe", "-s < awesomelogin.dat")
    Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("AnyConnect can't start and I don't know why")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I don't own AnyConnect but it should work like this :)

EDIT: Wow that was more code than I actually wanted to write... I hope it will help you anyway :D